# How To Turn every integer in a String , to a specific character (c++)

Tags: c++

for example lets say user just entered (2+3) , using cin>>string ,  now how can we just read all the characters in the string , and turn the integers to a specific character , like "i"

for example if user entered 2+3; we turn that string into i+i; ? any help is appreciated !

another example : (5+9)*3--->(i+i)*i

Comment: Wasn't this just asked?

Comment: Check [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/), __Return Value: A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is a decimal digit. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s;
cin >> s;

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {  //iterate trough entire string
    if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')  //if its a number
        s[i] = 'i';  //replace it with 'i'
}

cout << s << endl;
```

There are functions like `is_digit()` that could replace `if`, but this is without using any libraries etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
std::regex expr(R"(\d)");
auto result = std::regex_replace(string, expr, "i");
```

In case you wish `13+1` to be replaced with `i+i` rather than `ii+i`, that can be easily achieved with a small change to the regex.